# Use COM in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, dll, com, c++builder, c++builder-xe2

I'm new to COM libraries and I'm stuck on using a COM DLL in my C++ Builder (XE2) application. DLL is registered. Which are the steps that allows me to create objects belonging to such DLL and invoke their methods? I mean statically.

I couldn't find a tutorial, while I saw different ways:

1. Component > Import component > it produces a new wrapper unit... and then what?
2. import the DLL with an absolut path (why? it is registered in the system)

   ```
   #import "C:\Path\to\the\LIB1.dll" rename_namespace ("LIB1")
   ```

   ... and then what?
3. use `CoCreateInstance`... how exactly? without import/include?

In Visual C# I deal with it simply adding a reference and a `using`!

I'm very confused! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if the COM object is properly registered, you just drag and drop the new component into you window and start calling methods.

Comment: 1. Then you add the new wrapper unit into your project by including the .HPP file, and create an instance of the COM object in your code using one of the classes starting with `Co` from the .hpp file.

Comment: @GregorBrandt & KenWhite Would you be so kind to post the full solution as an answer? I did some of the things you said, but I don't know the whole solution step by step... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way (but tell me if there are better ones):

- Component > Import component... > Import a Type Library > select the library
- Unit Dir Name =  and uncheck "Generate Component Wrappers"
- "Add unit to MyProject.cbproj project" > Finish
- in the client class > File > Use Unit... > select the unit that was created
- in the client class write this code for using the COM DLL:

  ```
  CoInitialize(NULL); //Init COM library DLLs  

  ICompany *company;        

  HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance ( CLSID_Company,  
                                  NULL,  
                                  CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,  
                                  IID_ICompany,  
                                  (void**) &company );  
  if (SUCCEEDED (hr)) {  
       //TODO here you can use your company object!
       //and finally release such resource
       company->Release();  
  }  

  CoUninitialize();
  ```

Where `Company` was the original class, exposed by the DLL, which I wanted to intantiate.

[Introduction to COM - What It Is and How to Use It.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633/Introduction-to-COM-What-It-Is-and-How-to-Use-It) helped me a lot.

**Note** that this requires the **creation of *_TLB.* and *_OCX.* units**. Is there a way that avoids it?